# Flex Builder 3: syntax coloring, add keyword

Tags: flexbuilder, syntax-highlighting

I wish to know where I can add Keywords for the syntax coloring in Flex Builder - i need to extend it a little for my own sanity.

Answer (score 0):

Window > Flex > Editors > Syntax Coloring

If you are looking for sanity when building Flex apps try flashdevelop (flashdevelop.org)

Comment: That lets you change the color, not the list of keywords

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can.  I haven't been able to find anywhere in the settings or in the files installed with the app where you can change the list of keywords.

As the other poster said, try FlashDevelop.  I like it a lot more than FlexBuilder.

Comment: odd though, you would think you can add it somewhere in a xml

yeah I used to use flashdevelop, its great (autocompletion ftw!), but our devsqaud at work works with FB so its a good idea to keep the same working environment.

Comment: You'd think.  You'd also think eclipse would have built-in ways to tweak syntax coloring settings of things like HTML files, but it doesn't.  At least not without installing other plugins, despite the fact that it's coloring the files w/o the plugins...